# Jasmine .toHaveBeenCalledWith(aDate) not working

Tags: testing, jasmine

I'm inheriting some code, and I've got two of their tests that are still failing, not sure if they were before, or if it's because I have a different version of Jasmine (they were pre 2.0)

The test that is failing has this spy setup in the beforeEach

```
spyOn(datacontext, 'getImportLogForDate').and.callThrough();
```

Then in the test

```
controller.DepositDate = new Date();
controller.PerformActionThatCallsGetImportLogForDate();
expect(context.getImportLogForDate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('1', controller.DepositDate);
```

The resulting error is confounding because they are identical

Expected spy getImportLogForDate to have been called with **[ '1', Date(Thu Dec 04 2014 13:00:51 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)) ]** but actual calls were **[ '1', Date(Thu Dec 04 2014 13:00:51 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)) ]**.

Can I not verify functions have been called with a Date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is `PerformActionThatCallsGetImportLogForDate` doing with the date object? Jasmine compares date objects by their millisecond value so if it's off even by 1ms, they won't be equal, but you won't see that level of detail just reading the console output.

Alternatively, you have 2 other options.

Just test that a date object was used as the 2nd argument.

```
expect(context.getImportLogForDate)
    .toHaveBeenCalledWith('1', jasmine.any(Date));
```

Test that date value, but outside of a `toHaveBeenCalledWith`, in case of some specific weirdness with that matcher.

```
expect(context.getImportLogForDate.calls.mostRecent().args[0])
    .toEqual('1');
expect(context.getImportLogForDate.calls.mostRecent().args[1])
    .toEqual(controller.DepositDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found that when using `toHaveBeenCalledWith` for a specific `Date`, `jasmine.objectContaining` works great.

```
it('#userChangedMonth calls fetchData with end of month', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'fetchData').and.returnValue(true);
    const calendarChangedTo = new Date('2018-10-10 00:00:00');
    const endOfMonth = new Date('2018-10-31 23:59:59');
    component.userChangedMonth(calendarChangedTo);
    expect(component.fetchData).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining(endOfMonth));
  });
```